# Why can't moderators add "partial dupes" to the "list of dupes"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, dupehammer

A question may sometime be a combination of dupes of multiple other questions. If that happens, it should be possible - both before and after the question is closed as a dupe (with a dupehammer or otherwise) - for a moderator to add questions to the "list of dupes".

I know a "list of dupes" exists since I've seen questions marked as dupes of more than one question. So - why not make it editable with sufficient privileges?

This is motivated by [a recent experience of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495011/what-do-member-function-qualifiers-other-than-const-mean) (see the comments for the two dupes).

Comment: Partial dupes are only partial

Comment: People have to nominate possible duplicate for them to be listed.  A moderators duplicate vote by design closes a question immediately.