# Déjà vu implies glitch in the matrix: question became HNQ six times in two seconds

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, regression

In the first Matrix movie [Trinity says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_KmNZNT5xw):

> A déjà vu is usually a glitch in the matrix, it happens when they change something.

Related: [Why do the machines allow the memory of déjà vu to persist?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166507/51174)

---

---

[image: screenshot of the black cat déjà vu scene from the original Matrix] [image: screenshot of the black cat déjà vu scene from the original Matrix]

Screenshot of history for [Aquamation (alkaline hydrolysis) as alternative to burial or cremation; NY Catholic Conference and Catholic Church's current position?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/88815/54135) at `2022-01-02 22:51z` showing the question becoming HNQ six times between `2022-01-02 11:55:42z` and `11:55:44z`

[image: screenshot of history for https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/88815/54135 at 2022-01-02 22:51z]

[image: screenshot of history for https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/88815/54135 at 2022-01-02 22:51z]

Comment: not sure how to tag this; if it's a bug it's probably just a small one, unless...

Comment: @JohnOmielan should you have chosen the original one? That's also a duplicate and also *unanswered*

Comment: Note there are other related questions here, e.g., [How hot? Double hot (bug resurfaced?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362207/562482) and [Why has this question become hot twice within a few seconds of interval?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346518/562482).

Comment: @JohnOmielan yes, if this is to be closed, let's close as duplicate to the one with the best answers.

Comment: I chose the one I did because it is more recent, is apparently closer to what you experience, and due to the original one possibly being due to a different issue as it set to be "status-completed". Nonetheless, if you think it's better to close it as a duplicate of another post, such as the original one with an answer, then I believe that's also a good choice.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I still think that sending future readers to the best answer is the overriding criteria, isn't it? Maybe it isn't in meta, but that's just the criteria I've always used, keeping future readers in mind, and Stack Exchange is all about answers.

Comment: @uhoh I generally agree, but the original post's answer that my suggested one is stated as a duplicate of mostly resolves something that occurred earlier, so I wasn't sure if it was applicable to your case. Nonetheless, on rereading the answer, it does state "There is a chance that this will not completely eliminate the issue under high load, and we may need to add an [`UPDLOCK` hint][2] to the query as well." Since this is quite possibly what happened in your case, then it may be a better answer to link to. Regardless, at this point, it's up to you since I can't change my dupe vote.

Comment: @JohnOmielan okay got it. For future readers: we can change our dupe vote by withdrawing it, but we can not retarget our dupe votes to a different question. In this case there's no need to do that because it takes several votes and others will stop by and read the comments and choose their own targets.

Comment: John & uhoh, people with a Hammer (not John) could withdrawn and edit the banner that shows up upon duplicate closure. --- Since (somewhat) near duplicates are better than withdrawing completely and offering nothing (and multiple targets in the banner, if they are relevant, are better) I too tend not to withdraw the vote unless it's entirely incorrect.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the refined info!

Comment: uhoh, see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/282094 and why to have more than one duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289384/282094